# AJP configuration in JBoss 4.2.2 is not binding to the correct port

Tags: networking, jboss

I am looking into a strange problem where a JBoss 4.2.2 server is not binding to the correct AJP port. We have configured it to bind to 8009, but it is binding to 18129.

After attaching the debugger, I can see that for some reason, `org.jboss.services.binding.XSLTFileDelegate` is generating a temp file with this in it. The `XSLTFileDelegate` does an XSLT transform which includes the following variable declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="portAJP" select="$port - 71"/>
```

And sets the value of `$port` to be 18200, hence the binding to 18129.

What I don't understand is why JBoss is choosing to run `XSLTFileDelegate` in the first place. We have explicitly chosen to bind to 8009 in `<server>\deploy\jboss-web.deployer\server.xml`. We also have other JBoss instances in the same directory tree which are correctly binding to 8019, 8029 and so-on.

Is anyone able to shed some light on what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your JBoss server has been configured to use a different port mapping than the default. This is sometimes done in order to allow multiple JBoss instances to run on the same IP address.

Check out `conf/jboss-service.xml`, and look for a reference to `ServiceBindingManager`. It's normally commented out, but if you see it uncommented, then look for the attribute that looks something like this:

```
<attribute name="ServerName">ports-01</attribute>
```

This `ports-01` specifies a "shifted" set of ports for each network service, including AJP. These mappings are defined in `$JBOSS_HOME/docs/examples/binding-manager/sample-bindings.xml`.

If you comment out the `ServiceBindingManager` in `conf/jboss-service.xml`, the ports should revert back to their defaults.